# Percentage ratio within each bin in stacked histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, bins

I have a stacked histogram corresponding to three categories (Cat-I, II, III), so that in each bin I can see the frequency of each category. I would prefer to have the Y-axis showing the percentage ratio of each category in each bin so that the ratios of the three categories in each bin add up to 1. I tried the following approach to get the stacked histogram, any help on how to tweak the code so that I can show the percentage ratio would be highly appreciated. I know that setting density=True will give the probability density but I am not looking for it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data1=np.loadtxt('C:/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/Cat-I.txt')
data2=np.loadtxt('C:/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/Cat-II.txt')
data3=np.loadtxt('C:/Users/Hrihaan/Desktop/Cat-III.txt')
x1=data1[:,1]
x2=data2[:,1]
x3=data3[:,1]
bins= 8
bins_list = [301, 340, 372, 405, 431, 472, 514, 599, 949] # I defined the bins range so that I have bins of equal elements, the first 7 bins all have 23 elemnets where the last has 24
plt.hist([x1,x3,x2], bins=bins_list, histtype='bar', color=["mediumspringgreen", "pink", "lightskyblue"], stacked=True, edgecolor='dimgrey', linewidth=20, density=False)
```

Comment: Your example is not really a *working* example since we don't have access to the files in your computer.

Comment: I edited the text.

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert x1, x2, and x3 data into respective bins using qcut and then get the percentage by dividing by total for every bin. Say x1[0]/(x1[0]+x2[0]+x3[0])

```
pd.qcut(x1, q=bins_list, labels=False)
```